# How can I make a string of ASCII characters from a for loop (Python 3.3)?

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program that will create a randomly generated eight-character key (in ASCII characters). So far I have been able to get the 8 different numbers, then convert them into their equivalent ASCII character:

```
> import random
> for i in range(0,8):
>     key = random.randint(33,126)
>     key = chr(key)
>     print(key)
```

however when I run the program it prints (the output is at least always different):

```
> ~
> e
> E
> v
> k
> `
> (
> X
```

when ideally I would like it to print (with no spaces in-between):

```
> ~eEvk`(X
```

but I have tried so many methods (formatting included) to put it into a string but nothing has worked!
Sorry for the lengthy question, but I hope it made sense. An answer ASAP would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options for dealing with this.

First, if you want to `print()` each character but don't want the newline, you can tell it to keep output on the same line like this:

```
import random
for i in range(0,8):
    key = random.randint(33,126)
    key = chr(key)
    print(key, end='')
```

Another option would be to start with an empty string `s = ''` and add each key to it as you make them, and then print the whole string at the end:

```
import random
s = ''
for i in range(0,8):
    key = random.randint(33,126)
    s += chr(key)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Following on what you have done, you can add it to a list and then print the list at the end of the loop

```
import random
l = []
for i in range(0,8):
   key = random.randint(33,126)
   key = chr(key)
   l.append(key)
print("".join(l))
```

Comment: Or just `''.join(chr(random.randint(33,126)) for _ in range(8))`

Comment: That is even better indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import random
print("".join(chr(random.randint(33,126)) for _ in range(8)))
```

Or use string module:

```
import random
import string
print("".join(random.choice(string.printable) for _ in range(8)))
```

Comment: `string.printable` is slightly different than `range(33, 127)` for instance it includes tabs, carriage returns, line feeds... etc...

Comment: This was the best solution for me. Thanks!